# Integrate $e^{-\lvert x-y \rvert}$

Tags: integration, exponentiation

How do I integrate the following integral?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \! e^{-|x-y|} \, \mathrm{d}x.$$

My approach is the divide the calculation into two parts: 
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \! e^{-|x-y|} \, \mathrm{d}x + \int_{-\infty}^{0} \! e^{-|(-x)-y|} \, \mathrm{d}x.$$
and the my result is:
$$e^y + e^{-y}$$

I don't think my answer is correct and I couldn't find any similar calculation online. I really appreciate if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Split  the integral into integrals over $(y, \infty)$ and $(-\infty,y)$ instead of $(0, \infty)$ and $(-\infty,0)$.

Comment: This could also be a comment.

Comment: That's a great reminder. Is the reason for using y instead of 0 because of not considering the rest of the value outside y which would be 0? Also, I took your advice and the answer turns out to be 2. Am I correct?

Comment: @Jim Yes, your answer is correct.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy I am still having difficulty on understanding the techniques on choosing the appropriate range for such integration. Do you have more intuitive elaboration on why choosing $(y, \infty) $ instead of $(0, \infty) $? Will the range be the same if there isn't absolute sign?

Comment: The idea is to  get rid of the absolute value sign. $|y-x|=y-x$ if $x <y$ and $|y-x|=x-y$ if $x >y$ so you split the integral into  parts $x<y$ and $x >y$ @Jim